# Stripe - creating customer and saving summary card data using just two calls

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm saving a credit card as a payment method using stripe and then saving the card summary details to my own database.

The below code is working to do this.

However, it requires three calls.

Is there a way to get the summary card data from when I create a customer or any other way to do this in two calls

```
    stripe.customers.create({
        payment_method: req.body.paymentMethodID
        }).then(stripeCustomer => {     

            stripe.paymentMethods.list({customer: stripeCustomer.id, type: 'card'}).then(cardDetails => {

                User.findByIdAndUpdate(purchaser, {
                    stripeCustomerID: stripeCustomer.id,
                    savedPaymentDetails: {
                        card: cardDetails.data[0].card.brand,
                        last4: cardDetails.data[0].card.last4,
                        expiryMonth: cardDetails.data[0].card.exp_month,
                        expiryYear: cardDetails.data[0].card.exp_year
                    },

                }).then()               
            })
        })
```

The code on the front end is:

```
const cardElement = this.props.elements.getElement('card');

    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/saveCardDetails`).then(res => {

        this.props.stripe.confirmCardSetup(res.data.client_secret, {payment_method: {card: cardElement}}).then( confirmCardSetupRes => {

            if (confirmCardSetupRes.setupIntent.status === 'succeeded'){

                    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/paymentIntent`, objectToSend).then(res => {                    
                        this.props.upDateMessage(res.data.message)

                    })
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you share your front end code that is passing down the paymentMethodID? You should be able to pull out that summary data when you tokenize the payment method on the client and shouldn't need to list payment methods again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the question with the front end code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[stripe.confirmCardSetup](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup) returns a promise that is resolved with an object that contains either the `setupIntent` or an `error`. If successful, that `setupIntent` object will have a property `payment_method` and by default, that is the ID of the new PaymentMethod (tokenized payment details of the form "pm_xxx").

Often times, businesses want to show their customers which last4, brand, or other non-sensitive payment details related to the credit card used for a purchase. As you pointed out, you can retrieve those details by [listing the PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) filtering by customer and card type.

An alternative to making a separate fetch call on the server is to use the [Expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) feature of the API to "hydrate" or "expand" the full object for the PaymentMethod. We know the PaymentMethod is expandable by looking at the full API reference for a SetupIntent and seeing the "Expandable" label next to PaymentMethod.

[image]

I would recommend updating the call to `stripe.confirmCardSetup` to add an expand parameter for `payment_method` that way, the resulting `setupIntent` object will have the full card details for the resulting PaymentMethod.

For reference, that might look something like:

```
stripe.confirmCardSetup(
  '{{CLIENT_SECRET}}', {
  payment_method: {
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: {
      name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    },
  },
  expand: ['payment_method'],
});
```

With `expand: ['payment_method']` the resulting SetupIntent will have more data. Here's an example of the object the promise would be resolved with in the success case:

```
{
    "id": "seti_1GrRu6CZ6qsJgndJLpV8r95t",
    "object": "setup_intent",
    "cancellation_reason": null,
    "client_secret": "seti_1GrRu6CZ6qsJgndJLpV8r95t_secret_HQIVFzRdJsagSr88ElPvQiHViWZlPm4",
    "created": 1591549406,
    "description": null,
    "last_setup_error": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "next_action": null,
    "payment_method": {
        "id": "pm_1GrRuSCZ6qsJgndJhegm4jig",
        "object": "payment_method",
        "billing_details": {
            "address": {
                "city": null,
                "country": null,
                "line1": null,
                "line2": null,
                "postal_code": "23232",
                "state": null
            },
            "email": null,
            "name": "Jenny Rosen",
            "phone": null
        },
        "card": {
            "brand": "visa",
            "checks": {
                "address_line1_check": null,
                "address_postal_code_check": null,
                "cvc_check": null
            },
            "country": "US",
            "exp_month": 2,
            "exp_year": 2032,
            "funding": "credit",
            "generated_from": null,
            "last4": "4242",
            "three_d_secure_usage": {
                "supported": true
            },
            "wallet": null
        },
        "created": 1591549429,
        "customer": null,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {},
        "type": "card"
    },
    "payment_method_types": [
        "card"
    ],
    "single_use": null,
    "status": "succeeded",
    "usage": "off_session"
}
```

For your specific case, I would recommend passing some of those details in addition to the ID of the PaymentMethod back to the server. e.g.:

```
objectToSend.paymentMethodID = confirmCardSetupRes.setupIntent.payment_method.id;
objectToSend.card = confirmCardSetupRes.setupIntent.payment_method.card;

axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/paymentIntent`, objectToSend).then(res => {                    
  this.props.upDateMessage(res.data.message)
})
```

Comment: Noticed a problem with this fix. It doesn't work for cards that require authentication. The additional data isn't available in SetUpIntent for these cards. Is there a fix for this or will I have to re-introduce the additional call at the back end

Comment: @Colfah I am at the same crossroads, but I think I would probably go with passing payment_method to server and in the server route, I will make a payment_retrieve() which will get me all these data, and then save those details to db or whatever.

Comment: Looks like it is working for cards that require authentication also now so you can save yourself a call if you use this fix